# How do I make my Discord bot stay in the voice channel for the length of time of a specific mp3 file?

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I've been developing a bot for my personal discord server and so far it's played mp3s that are all a set length, so I tell the bot to sleep for a certain amount of time depending on how long the mp3 is. Now with my new command there will be mp3s of different lengths being played, and I'm not sure where to go from here. You can see in my code how I make it sleep, but this will no longer work as the mp3s might be very long or might be very short. I am trying to figure out a way to grab info about the mp3 through python and tell it to sleep for the length of the mp3. Could someone please help me go about this or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

In the past I tried to use a command along the lines of vc.wait but the bot kept joining and then leaving immediately. The sleep command worked perfectly for my past uses so I just used that instead.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def tts(ctx):
    #get message content and send to google text to speech api
    msg = ctx.message.content
    tts = gTTS(msg[5:])

    #here is where the mp3 is made and saved
    tts.save('message.mp3')

    #find length of mp3

    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    vc = await channel.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('./message.mp3')
    player = vc.play(source)

    #the method I've been using for mp3s, increasing or decreasing manually 
#per command based on mp3 length. This is the command that I now need to be 
#dynamic. Replace 15 with length of mp3.
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await vc.disconnect(force=True)
```

I do not expect anything however I hope to find some help or a nudge in the right direction in order to find the length of the mp3 on the spot and adjust bot's time spent in voice channel accordingly. Thank you. Sorry my code is so sloppy, it's just a personal project and I didn't ever expect anyone to see it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voice) for a voice client, you can create a callback function in `vc.play(source)`, maybe something like this:

```
async def playCallback(error):
    await vc.disconnect(force=True)
.
.
.

player = vc.player(source, after=playCallback)
```

Let me know if this works - happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

By changing these lines:

```py
source = FFmpegPCMAudio('./message.mp3')
player = vc.play(source)
```

With these line:

```py
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('./message.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
```

After playing audio file is finished, bot will automatically disconnect.